# What type of discontinuity is this?

Tags: calculus

For the function $f(x) = \sqrt{2x + 3}$ I was able to find the points of discontinuity but unable to classify the type of discontinuity.

The points of discontinuity in $f(x)$ are all values of $x$ that are less than $-3 \over 2$.

The types of discontinuities I learned are

- jump discontinuity; here, $f(x)$ does not show any jumps in the graph so I eliminated this possibility.
- infinite discontinuity; there appears to be no asymptotes in the graph of $f(x)$
- oscillating discontinuity; no oscillation occurs in the graph of $f(x)$
- removable discontinuity; no holes in $f(x)$

If it's not one of those, then what kind of discontinuity does $f(x)$ have? The question's directions in my textbook asks for the points of discontinuity *and* the type of discontinuity.

Comment: What makes you think $f$ is discontinuous at $-3/2$? :)

Comment: @user86418, *less than* -3/2 :). I set $2x$ equal to $-3$ and solved for $x$. Substituting $-3/2$ in $f(x)$ produces 0, so anything less than that would not produce a real number

Comment: @pcnThird: According to Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities , your function falls in the third category; that is, it is an essential discontinuity.

Comment: Real numbers $x_0 < -3/2$ aren't in the domain of $f$, so no notion of "continuity" at such an $x_0$ is defined. (The wikipedia article linked by @user99680 specifically addresses functions defined in a neighborhood of $x_0$, which isn't the case here.)

Comment: @user86418: I was referring to x=$-3/2$.

Comment: Fair enough, though $f$ isn't defined in a neighborhood of $-3/2$, either. (If one declares $f(x) = \sqrt{2x + 3}$ discontinuous at $-3/2$, the extreme value theorem (for example) becomes vacuous, since there would be no continuous functions on a closed, bounded interval. :)

Comment: @user99680: $f$ is continuous at $x=-3/2$. When taking limits, you are only allowed to approach the point through other points lying in the domain of the function. (I should add that, since it wasn't stated, I am assuming the domain is $[0,\infty)$ and that $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: @user86418: Isn't [-3/2, 1) , say , a degenerate neighborhood? And, sorry, I don't get your point; if the limit exists to the right- and left- , respectively of the endpoints of [a,b], then you can say the function is continuous in [a,b]. Of course, your definition is workable too, arguably more common, familiar than mine. Sorry if I'm "over-lawyering" my definitions, tho :).

Comment: Eh, sorry, correcting comment: domain is $[-\frac32,\infty)$. Sorry! Credit to @user127.0.0.1 (aka Mr. Loopback)

Comment: @user99680: The wikipedia page assumes $f$ is defined "on both sides" of $x_0$, namely in some interval $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$, so that classification doesn't apply to $f(x) = \sqrt{2x+3}$ at $-3/2$. I read your first comment as claiming the OP's $f$ was discontinuous at $-3/2$, which is not the case. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In complete agreement with the other answerers, I would like to say that @pcnThird’s question reflects a misconception that is fostered by many Calculus texts, which give often misleading and sometimes downright erroneous descriptions or definitions of discontinuity. It *does not make sense* to speak of continuity or discontinuity of a function $f$ at a point where $f$ is not defined. So, it is simply wrong to say that the function $f(x)=1/x$ is discontinuous at zero; rather it just isn’t defined there.

A related error of many of our texts is to say that a function is continuous if its graph can be drawn without raising the pencil from the paper. But that is only the case when the domain of the function is an interval. When the domain is disconnected, the graph in fact will always break up into more than one connected piece. (end of sermon)

Answer (score 1):

If you intend $f:[-\frac32,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is continuous at $-3/2$.

Comment: $-3/2\notin \left[0,\,\infty\right)$ ...

Comment: @user127.0.0.1: Whoops, will correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a function to be discontinuous at a point, you should have that the function is defined at that point. So, it does not make sense to study the continuity properties at $x$ for $x<-3/2$. This function is continuous, in its domain.